# Android ArrayList filter special characters

Tags: android, arraylist, filter

In my app, I have an ArrayList with all my Contacts of my Phone Book.

Unfortunately there are records like "tom@test.com". How can i remove all the records with special characters, so that i only get letters-only ones?

```
        Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME }, null,
            null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
    int i = cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
    for (cur.moveToFirst(); !cur.isAfterLast(); cur.moveToNext()) {
        contacts.add(cur.getString(i));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

what is contacts??
I think u must replace every ur arraylist with replaceAll old char to new char

```
for (Contact contact : contacts)
   contact.getText.replaceAll("@"," ");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be something like this (if this is not the solution for the problem write me :)):

```
boolean specialChar;
    Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME }, null,
            null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
    int i = cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
    for (cur.moveToFirst(); !cur.isAfterLast(); cur.moveToNext()) {
        //          contacts.add(cur.getString(i));
        specialChar = false;
        for(char c : cur.getString(i).toCharArray()){
            specialChar = false;
            if(!Character.isDigit(c) || !Character.isLetterOrDigit(c)){
                specialChar = true;
            }
            if(!specialChar){
                contacts.add(cur.getString(i));
            }
        }
    }
```